# Linked list in C – search method

Tags: c, dynamic, data-structures, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

As at the last time, suppose we have doubly linked list of nodes

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Node {
    int value;
    struct Node* next;
    struct Node* prev;
} Node;

typedef struct LinkedList {
    Node *first;
    Node *last;
} LinkedList;

void initList(LinkedList* l) {
    l->first = NULL;
    l->last = NULL;
}
```

and my task is to code search method, which should find a node with given value

```
Node* search(LinkedList *list, int value) { ... }
```

well, my attempt follows

```
Node* search(LinkedList *list, int value) {

    Node *node = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    if (node == NULL)
        return NULL;

    node->value = value;
    node->prev = NULL;
    node->next = list->first;

    while((node->value != value) && (node->next != NULL)){
        node->prev = node->next;
        node->next = (node->next)->next;
    }

    return node;
}
```

according to the implemenatation tests (this is not my job :-)

```
void test_search_exist() {
    printf("Test 3: ");

    LinkedList l;
    initList(&l);

    Node n1, n2;
    n1.value = 1;
    n1.next = &n2;
    n1.prev = NULL;
    n2.value = 2;
    n2.next = NULL;
    n2.prev = &n1;
    l.first = &n1;
    l.last = &n2;

    Node *i = search(&l, 2);

    if (i == &n2) {
        printf("OK\n");
    }else{
        printf("FAIL\n");
    }
}

void test_search_not_exist(){
    printf("Test 4: ");

    LinkedList l;
    initList(&l);

    Node n1, n2;
    n1.value = 1;
    n1.next = &n2;
    n1.prev = NULL;
    n2.value = 2;
    n2.next = NULL;
    n2.prev = &n1;
    l.first = &n1;
    l.last = &n2;

    Node *i = search(&l, 3);

    if (i == NULL) {
        printf("OK\n");
    }else{
        printf("FAIL\n");
    }
}
```

my code breaks either for existing or non-existing nodes. So is there any logic mistake or whatever?

Comment: If you're tasked with **searching** for an **existing** item, why are you **allocating** an item?

Comment: @Amit the node with searched value may exist, but might not as well. (Btw what did I do wrong that reputation is currently "-2"? :-) )

Comment: You initialize node->value with value, but check for node->value == value, this will always be true since you dont update it

Comment: I don't know who voted and why, but I do know that if you can't figure out what I wrote, you have to learn. There's no point asking questions if you have no basic understanding.

Comment: @Taredon so in body of cycle I need to add somathing like node->value = (node->next)->value ?

Comment: @Amit yes, you're right, that I have to learn, however if I known all what I needed, I woudn't have any reason to put here the question.

Comment: No. You have to **learn**. A lot. From the ground up. Thoroughly. At length. What you're doing now is like asking a pilot to help you land an airplane because you keep crashing it - but you don't even know what makes it fly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Firstly:** Dont allocate within search. The data members already exist, since you created them ahead.
**Secondly:** Iterate through the list and check every node for it's value.

```
Node* search(LinkedList *list, int value) 
{
    Node *node = list->first;
    Node *found = NULL;

    while(node != NULL)
    {
        if(node->value == value)
        {
            found = node;
            break;
        }

        node = node->next;
    }

    return found;
}
```

To be more specific with the error(s) you made:

You allocated a node then filled it with the pointers of the first node, but with the value you were searching for. Then you started to loop over the list with the condition to stop when node->value equals the value you were searching for. Since node->value was initialized with the value your were searching for, this comparison will **always** be false (since its the same), the loop will be terminated and you get a bad result.

Besides this, your original code would result in a memory leak, since you malloc a new node, but you dont free it.